# can anyone tell me what mistake on this code

Tags: javascript

Please correct me if I am wrong

```
<html>
<body>

<script>

function newyear() {
alert("all the best");
}
>

</script>
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="newyear()" value="newyear" />

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: none, it works https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/5q906031/

Comment: extra > is the issue before </script> tag

Comment: The repeated "Please correct..." is just annoying.  This is a forum for grown-ups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>
<body>

<script>

function newyear() {
alert("all the best");
}
// remove the extra character here
</script>
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="newyear()" value="newyear" />

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra character(>). Remove it and your code is fine.
Like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
   function newyear() {
   alert("all the best");
   }
</script>
<form>
  <input type="button" onclick="newyear()" value="newyear" />

</form>
</body>
```